# Getting this error in nuxt: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, wavesurfer.js

i'm using nuxt.js and i want to pass current song time to vuex.

but passing data just working once.

this is my data:

```
currentSongTime: {
          second: 0,
          minute: 0,
          total: 0
        }
```

mounted:

```
this.WaveSurfer.on('seek', (position) => {
        this.currentSongTime.second = parseInt(position * this.WaveSurfer.getDuration() % 60);
        this.currentSongTime.minute = parseInt((this.WaveSurfer.getCurrentTime() / 60) % 60);
        this.currentSongTime.total = parseInt(position * this.WaveSurfer.getDuration());

        this.$store.commit('setCurrentSongTime', this.currentSongTime);
      });
```

index.js (vuex):

```
export const state = () => ({
  currentAudioTime: {}
});

export const mutations = {
  setCurrentSongTime(state, val) {
    state.currentAudioTime = val;
  }
};
```

it's just working once, and after that, i get this error message:

```
[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

i don't know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly setting the component data as `Vuex` state, and this causes problem because when you modify the component data you also directly mutate the state outside the mutation handlers. A quick fix is to clone this object before assigning it as a `vuex` state:

```
this.$store.commit('setCurrentSongTime', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentSongTime)));
```